# Carousel dots aren't visible when I trying to dynamic my HTML components

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, laravel

[View Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNZ9x.png)

Please visit the following image to check the actual preview.

HTML Codes with LARAVEL keywords:

```
<div id="reccomended" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)

<div class="item">
    <a href="{{ route('doctors.details', [$doctor->id]) }}">
        <div class="views"><i class="icon-eye-7"></i>140</div>
        <div class="title">
            <h4>{{ $doctor->name }}<em>Pediatrician - Cardiologist</em></h4>
        </div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x500.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>

@endforeach

<div class="item">
    <a href="detail-page.html">
        <div class="views"><i class="icon-eye-7"></i>120</div>
        <div class="title">
            <h4>Dr. Julia Holmes<em>Pediatrician</em></h4>
        </div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x500.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Carousel
$('#reccomended, #staff').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items: 2,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        600: {
            items: 2
        },
        1000: {
            items: 4
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```css
.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* fix firefox animation glitch */ }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* fix for flashing background */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); }
  .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
  .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
  .owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled {
    display: none; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
  .owl-carousel .owl-dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,
  .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
  .owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl; }
  .owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right; }

/* No Js */
.no-js .owl-carousel {
  display: block; }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Animate Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .animated {
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both; }

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
  z-index: 0; }

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
  z-index: 1; }

.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut; }

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }
  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Auto Height Plugin
 */
.owl-height {
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out; }

/*
 *  Owl Carousel - Lazy Load Plugin
 */
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  /**
      This is introduced due to a bug in IE11 where lazy loading combined with autoheight plugin causes a wrong
      calculation of the height of the owl-item that breaks page layouts
     */ }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""], .owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]) {
    max-height: 0; }
  .owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
    transform-style: preserve-3d; }



/**
 * Owl Carousel v2.3.4
 * Copyright 2013-2018 David Deutsch
 * Licensed under: SEE LICENSE IN https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */
/*
 *  Default theme - Owl Carousel CSS File
 */
.owl-theme .owl-nav {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  .owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-'] {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px; }
    .owl-theme .owl-nav [class*='owl-']:hover {
      background: #869791;
      color: #FFF;
      text-decoration: none; }
  .owl-theme .owl-nav .disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: default; }

.owl-theme .owl-nav.disabled + .owl-dots {
  margin-top: 10px; }

.owl-theme .owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline; }
    .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      margin: 5px 7px;
      background: #D6D6D6;
      display: block;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
      transition: opacity 200ms ease;
      border-radius: 30px; }
    .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span, .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
      background: #869791; }
```

The dots are visible when I kept the static items. But when I fetch the dynamic data from backend the the dots are not visible.

Can your please solve the issue. If you need further css code then just give me a response. I'll share the respective codes here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provided the respective codes here. Please solve it.